# Possible unhandled promise rejection on hardware back press

Tags: react-native

I have set up a store function

```
export const storeData = async text => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem("notes")
            .then((notes) => {
                const noteList = notes ? JSON.parse(notes) : [];
                noteList.push(text);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(noteList));
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error saving" + error);
    }
};
```

When calling from the header back button it works as intended

```
navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {
            storeData(text).then(() => {
navigation.goBack();
         }
        }} />
      )
    });
```

But when using it from the hardware back button it gives me an "unhandled promise rejection, undefined is not an object. evaluating _this.navigation".

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
        storeData(text).then(() => {
          this.navigation.goBack();
        });
    });
    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [text]);
```

Can anyone see what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: put a return true at the end of the hardwareBackPress handler function

Comment: @guruparan-giritharan if i add it to the end of the hardwareBackPress handler function it will not take me back to previous screen, and still gives me the error =(

Comment: seems like something to do with accessing the context, if you do it without storing data, does it work ?
does the this.navigation has a value ?
if possible please share the whole component code

Comment: @guruparan-giritharan No, it doesn't seem to have a value, but when i used this it took me back so i assumed it did.

Comment: it goes back as you didnt return true to stop the handling at back button level

Comment: better check this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2115#issuecomment-314291423

Comment: I tried the method suggested by the docs by using useNavigation to access the navigation (useNavigation().goBack();). It works, but instead I get a warning for invalid hook call.

Answer (score 0):

replace `this` by `props`. `this`key word is used mainly in class components here i  its a functional components so navigation is reached by `props.navigation`

Comment: @b-mohammad when i don't use this i instead get a "the action "go_back" was not handled by any navigator" error.

Answer (score 0):

The full code would look like

```
function EditNoteScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const backAction = () => {
    storeData(text).then(() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      navigation.goBack();
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
      backAction();
    });

    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => {
          backAction();
        }} />
      )
    });

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [text]);
```

Comment: It works when called from the header back button, but when used by the hardware back button it gives an "the action "go_back" was not handled by any navigator" error, which is very confusing. :S

Answer (score 0):

If I simply have my storage function run with the hardware back press the code will work and the hardware back buttons default behavior will take me back, but then the new item will not show up until refreshed, which is why i want the back behavior delayed until saving is done.

One way to ignore this would simply be to update the flatlist again on state change, but I would rather have the information there from the refresh rather then popping in.